# Building dynamic SQL queries in .net 2?

Tags: c#, sql, .net-2.0, dynamic-sql

I could be re-inventing the wheel - but..

I need to allow a user to be able to build 'customer reports' from our database - which will be from a GUI.

They can't have access to SQL just a list of Tables (Data groups) and columns within those groups.

They also have the ability to create Where clauses (criteria).

I've looked around Google - but nothing cropped up.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the  answers! We ended up doing this ourselves through a collection of views!

For instances:

- Sales View
- Customer View

The views already take care of most of the joining between tables and return as much joined data as they can.

The user then selects what columns they could like to see from each view and we do the join between the views at code level.

The resulting statement is very small as the views take most of the work out of it.

Answer (score 0):

well my recommendation, Developer express have some amazing end user criteria builder, you can use theirs.

there are other controls to create end users criteria , like 
http://devtools.korzh.com/query-builder-net/

I hope that help you

both controls above abstract the data acess layer so your end users wont have access to send a direct query to the database. The controls only build the criteria and its your work to send the query to the database.

Answer (score 0):

As a precurser to my answer, there are a number of expensive products out there like Izenda (www.izenda.com) that will do this very elegantly...

If you want to roll your own (and to speak to your question) you can fake this pretty quickly (and yes, this does not scale well to more than about 4 joins) like this:

1. Create a join statement that encompasses all of your tables that you want to use.
2. Create a dictionary of all available fields you want to expose to the user such as this: Dictionary = Dictionary<[Pretty displayable name], [**fully qualified** Sql field name]>
3. Let the user build a select list of fields they want to see and conditions they want add from the dictionary above and use the dictionary value to concat the sql string together that is necessary to return their results.

(I'm skipping quite a bit of validation work about making sure that the user doesn't try to mis-type the condition and such, but essentially point of this is that for a small collection of tables you can create a static "from" statement and then safely tack on the concat'ed "select" and "where" that the user builds)

Note that I've worked on some systems that actually stored the relationships of the table and compiled the most efficient "from" statement possible... that is not a huge stretch from this answer, it's just a bit more work.

Answer (score 0):

I *strongly* recommend going with an existing product like Crystal Reports, Sql Server Report Builder, or Infomaker.  It's just so *easy* to get something that seems to work, but leaves you open for an sql injection attack.

If you do go ahead, I recommend using a separate sql connection for these reports.  This connection should have a user account that only has read privileges anywhere in the database.